# mongodb: query first few rows where sum of specific column is greater or equal than C

Tags: mongodb

Suppose we have a mongodb collection with 2 columns: id, c

```
1,2
2,6
3,1
...
```

Now I would like to select first few rows where sum of column c is greater or equal than `C`

In the above case, 
if C=1, return first 1 row.
if C=8, return first 2 rows.
if C=9, return first 3 rows.

Answer (score 1):

**Query**

It could be done using *aggregation framework*. Consider the next *aggregation pipeline*

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
  {
    $group: 
      { 
        "_id": null, 
        "ds": { $push: "$$ROOT" }, 
        "cs": { $push: "$c" } 
      } 
  }, /* (1) */
  { $unwind: "$ds" }, /* (2) */
  { 
    $project: 
      { 
        "_id": "$ds._id", 
        "c": "$ds.c", 
        "cs": { $slice: [ "$cs", "$ds._id" ] } 
      } 
  }, /* (3):  */
  { $unwind: "$cs" },  /* (4) */
  { 
    $group: 
      { 
        "_id": "$_id", 
        "c": { $first: "$c" }, 
        "csum": { $sum: "$cs" } 
      } 
  }, /* (5) */
  { 
    $group: 
      { 
        "_id": null, 
        "ds": { $push: "$$ROOT" }, 
        "gteC": 
          { 
            $push: 
              { 
                $cond: 
                  { 
                    if: { "$gte": [ "$csum", SET_DESIRED_VALUE_FOR_C_HERE ] }, 
                    then: "$$ROOT", 
                    else: { } 
                  } 
              } 

          } 
      } 
  }, /* (6) */
  { 
    $project: 
      { 
        "_id": 0,
        "docs": 
          { 
            $filter: 
              { 
                input: "$ds", 
                "as": "doc", 
                cond: { $lte: [ "$$doc.csum", { $min: "$gteC.csum" } ] }
              }
          }
      }
  }, /* (7) */
  { $unwind: "$docs" }, /* (8) */ 
  { $project: { "_id": "$docs._id", "c": "$docs.c" } } /* (9) */
]);
```

**Results**

> C = 1 => `{ "_id": 1, "c": 2 }`
>
> C = 8 => `[ { "_id": 2, "c": 6 }, { "_id": 1, "c": 2 } ]`
>
> C = 9 => `[ { "_id": 3, "c": 1 }, { "_id": 2, "c": 6 }, { "_id": 1, "c": 2 } ]`
>
> C = 10 =>

**Explanation**

The basic idea behind it is to construct *helper array* for each document in the collection (***stages 1-3***)

```
{ "_id" : 1, "c" : 2 } -> cs = [ 2 ]
{ "_id" : 2, "c" : 6 } -> cs = [ 2, 6 ]
{ "_id" : 3, "c" : 1 } -> cs = [ 2, 6, 1 ]
```

using [**`$slice`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/slice/) *array aggregation operator* and then replace it with sum of all elements it contains (***stages 4-5***)

```
{ "_id" : 1, "c" : 2 } -> csum = 2
{ "_id" : 2, "c" : 6 } -> csum = 8
{ "_id" : 3, "c" : 1 } -> csum = 9
```

using [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage and [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) *group accumulator operator*.

Then construct another helper array of documents with `csum >= C` (***stage 6***)

```
/* Ex. (C = 8) */
gteC = [ { "_id" : 3, "c" : 1, "csum" : 9 }, { "_id" : 2, "c" : 6, "csum" : 8 } ]
```

The last step is to retrieve all documents with `csum <= Min { gteC.csum }`. This is done using [**`$filter`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) *array aggregation operator* (***stage 7***).

However, I am *not* sure this is *the most efficient* aggregation pipeline (will be grateful for any improvement suggestions) to achieve what you want.

**PS** Before testing the query don't forget to change the name of collection and replace SET_DESIRED_VALUE_FOR_C_HERE.